# Extra title in attribute option title

Tags: attributes, language

I having extra language(Australia,Brazil,Cameroon,Canada, extra English,French,German,Italy,Russia) as in picture 1.
But I can't find them in my store, as picture 2, any way to remove them?
[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]

Comment: Check the ids of your store views that appear in the attribute option labels, and see if they are linked to a store and a website. You may have orphan store views.

Comment: Alright, I have removed from core_store table manually, is this gonna affect anything? As I didn't want or putting any content to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please first to rebuid index management and clear a cache.**

**Magento Deleting Stores Manually**

```
If you ever run into a situation where you need to remove stores
or websites from Magento using the database.
```

**You can do so using the tables listed below:?**

> 1. core_website - to remove websites
> 2. core_store  - to remove store
> 3. views core_store_group - to remove stores